# Unable to assign a question word ( WHO or WHAT ) to a word using Spacy

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy

I have below 2 sentences.

**Sentence1: A man is moving.**

**Sentence2: A truck is moving.**

My problem statement is to assign a question word to the above two sentences. I need to assign WHO for the first sentence and WHAT for the second sentence.

What I have done is written an algorithm which assigns WHO, WHAT to both the sentences. The reason being, man and truck are both nouns. The pos is NOUN for both man and truck and also NN is the tag for both the words ( man and truck ) I have written the logic in a way, if relation is nsubj and is  NOUN/NN, then return the question word WHO and WHAT.

Is there a way to get only WHO when the sentence is involving a human being and WHAT when it involves a dog/non-living things.

Is this something which can be accomplished using Spacy which I am missing very obviously.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a one liner or anything for this in spacy, to my knowledge. Linguistically, they are both nouns. What you need is more information about these nouns, what categories they are in. You want to assign WHO when the category is person, and WHAT when the category is object. The go-to source of categories like that is Wordnet. There is a spacy/wordnet integration library, [repo](https://github.com/recognai/spacy-wordnet). You'll want to traverse up the tree of [hypernyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy). The shared root of the tree for both words is "physical entity", but maybe if you end up at "animal" you assign WHO, otherwise you assign WHAT..?

You can explore the wordnet hierarchies [here](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=hominid&i=23&h=10011001100110000110000000000#c).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest on my question and your suggestion. Apologies for getting back to you a bit late.  I will look into this and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried all options. Its getting very difficult to find an one size fits all solution. It may work for Truck and man, but now working for some other words. Thinking how to solve it. But as of now, no luck.